# UIWebView crashing app on resource load

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I know this is probably a long shot, but I'm seeing this crash in the wild (unable to re-produce).  And I can't figure out why it's happening.  I believe that what I'm seeing is my UIWebView attempting to call it's delegate for a resource load but finding that the delegate is deallocated. However, my application doesn't deallocate the UIWebView, just backgrounds it for various reasons, and my WebViewDelegate doesn't implement the `webView:identifierForInitialRequest:fromDataSource:` method.  I've pared down the below crash long to what I think are the offending threads and would love if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001926abbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                          0x0000000186a10b78 -[UIWebView webView:identifierForInitialRequest:fromDataSource:] + 88
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182067dec __invoking___ + 140
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181f66658 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 292
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181f6b1ec -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64
5   WebKitLegacy                   0x00000001907e5750 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 168
6   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182065c5c ___forwarding___ + 436
7   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181f6b088 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 88
8   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182067dec __invoking___ + 140
9   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181f66658 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 292
10  WebCore                        0x000000018f99a8f0 _ZL20HandleDelegateSourcePv + 116
11  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018201a320 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
12  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001820195c4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
13  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182017674        0x181f3c000 + 708
14  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181f45660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
15  GraphicsServices               0x000000018b07f5a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
16  UIKit                          0x000000018684a980 UIApplicationMain + 1484
17  IMNOTTELLING                   0x0000000100195fd8 main (main.m:14)
18  libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000192d06a04 start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000192e1f078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   WebCore                        0x000000018f97fb98 _ZL19SendDelegateMessageP12NSInvocation + 612
2   WebKitLegacy                   0x000000019081aec0 _Z24CallResourceLoadDelegatePFP11objc_objectS0_P13objc_selectorzEP7WebViewS1_S0_S0_ + 152
3   WebKitLegacy                   0x00000001907e2364 _ZN20WebFrameLoaderClient32assignIdentifierToInitialRequestEmPN7WebCore14DocumentLoaderERKNS0_15ResourceRequestE + 316
4   WebCore                        0x000000018f8ef2d4 _ZN7WebCore14ResourceLoader15willSendRequestERNS_15ResourceRequestERKNS_16ResourceResponseE + 156
5   WebCore                        0x000000018f8ef1b8 _ZN7WebCore17SubresourceLoader15willSendRequestERNS_15ResourceRequestERKNS_16ResourceResponseE + 336
6   WebCore                        0x000000018f8eeec4 _ZN7WebCore14ResourceLoader4initERKNS_15ResourceRequestE + 308
7   WebCore                        0x000000018f8eebc0 _ZN7WebCore17SubresourceLoader12startLoadingEv + 52
8   WebCore                        0x000000018f8eeb0c _ZN7WebCore21ResourceLoadScheduler20servePendingRequestsEPNS0_15HostInformationENS_20ResourceLoadPriorityE + 520
9   WebCore                        0x000000018f8edf54 _ZN7WebCore21ResourceLoadScheduler23scheduleSubresourceLoadEPNS_5FrameEPNS_14CachedResourceERKNS_15ResourceRequestENS_20ResourceLoadPriorityERKNS_21ResourceLoaderOptionsE + 80
10  WebCore                        0x000000018f8eca84 _ZN7WebCore14CachedResource4loadEPNS_20CachedResourceLoaderERKNS_21ResourceLoaderOptionsE + 1176
11  WebCore                        0x000000018f8ea558 _ZN7WebCore20CachedResourceLoader15requestResourceENS_14CachedResource4TypeERNS_21CachedResourceRequestE + 1236
12  WebCore                        0x000000018faebbf8 _ZN7WebCore20CachedResourceLoader18requestRawResourceERNS_21CachedResourceRequestE + 40
13  WebCore                        0x000000018faeb74c _ZN7WebCore24DocumentThreadableLoader11loadRequestERKNS_15ResourceRequestENS_19SecurityCheckPolicyE + 248
14  WebCore                        0x000000018fc9f5fc _ZN7WebCore24DocumentThreadableLoader34makeSimpleCrossOriginAccessRequestERKNS_15ResourceRequestE + 124
15  WebCore                        0x000000018fc9f448 _ZN7WebCore24DocumentThreadableLoader28makeCrossOriginAccessRequestERKNS_15ResourceRequestE + 256
16  WebCore                        0x000000018fc9f288 _ZN7WebCore24DocumentThreadableLoaderC2ERNS_8DocumentERNS_22ThreadableLoaderClientENS0_16BlockingBehaviorERKNS_15ResourceRequestERKNS_23ThreadableLoaderOptionsE + 504
17  WebCore                        0x000000018fc9f044 _ZN7WebCore24DocumentThreadableLoader6createERNS_8DocumentERNS_22ThreadableLoaderClientERKNS_15ResourceRequestERKNS_23ThreadableLoaderOptionsE + 68
18  WebCore                        0x000000018faeb624 _ZN7WebCore16ThreadableLoader6createEPNS_22ScriptExecutionContextEPNS_22ThreadableLoaderClientERKNS_15ResourceRequestERKNS_23ThreadableLoaderOptionsE + 156
19  WebCore                        0x000000018faeb24c _ZN7WebCore14XMLHttpRequest13createRequestERi + 1132
20  WebCore                        0x000000018faeadc0 _ZN7WebCore14XMLHttpRequest4sendERKN3WTF6StringERi + 832
21  WebCore                        0x000000018faea61c _ZN7WebCore16JSXMLHttpRequest4sendEPN3JSC9ExecStateE + 252
22  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018384262c        0x1834ac000 + 26140
23  JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000183842058 llint_entry + 24648
24  JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000183842058 llint_entry + 24648
25  JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000183841ff4        0x1834ac000 + 24548
26  JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000183841ff4        0x1834ac000 + 24548
27  JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000183841ff4        0x1834ac000 + 24548
28  JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000183841ff4        0x1834ac000 + 24548
29  JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000183842058 llint_entry + 24648
30  JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018383bdf0 callToJavaScript + 304
31  JavaScriptCore                 0x00000001837aa454 _ZN3JSC7JITCode7executeEPNS_2VMEPNS_14ProtoCallFrameE + 44
32  JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000183515554 _ZN3JSC11Interpreter11executeCallEPNS_9ExecStateEPNS_8JSObjectENS_8CallTypeERKNS_8CallDataENS_7JSValueERKNS_7ArgListE + 416
33  JavaScriptCore                 0x00000001836414a4 _ZN3JSC4callEPNS_9ExecStateENS_7JSValueENS_8CallTypeERKNS_8CallDataES2_RKNS_7ArgListEPS2_ + 88
34  WebCore                        0x000000018f8de73c _ZN7WebCore15ScheduledAction24executeFunctionInContextEPN3JSC14JSGlobalObjectENS1_7JSValueEPNS_22ScriptExecutionContextE + 488
35  WebCore                        0x000000018f8de2d0 _ZN7WebCore15ScheduledAction7executeEPNS_8DocumentE + 140
36  WebCore                        0x000000018f8dda74 _ZN7WebCore8DOMTimer5firedEv + 504
37  WebCore                        0x000000018f8dd4dc _ZN7WebCore12ThreadTimers24sharedTimerFiredInternalEv + 144
38  WebCore                        0x000000018f8dd420 _ZN7WebCoreL10timerFiredEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPv + 32
39  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018201a20c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 24
40  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182019ebc __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 884
41  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182017908        0x181f3c000 + 1368
42  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181f45660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
43  WebCore                        0x000000018f964554 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 464
44  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000192ebbe7c _pthread_body + 160
45  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000192ebbdd8 _pthread_start + 156
46  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000192eb8fac thread_start + 0
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?  I have had a similar crash report.

Comment: Not sure if we ever actually solved the root cause, but we found some web views where we weren't retaining our delegate properly and so some javascript callbacks were attempting to call through and crashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this issue for a while as well before I found out the cause. I had been calling `removeFromSuperview` on the `UIView` containing our `UIWebView` without `nil`ing out the `UIWebView`'s delegate. So I guess the `UIWebView` must have an active view hierarchy at all times unless its delegate is `nil`.

Objective-C

```
// Make sure this code is called before `removeFromSuperview`
webView.delegate = nil;
[webView loadHTMLString: @"about:blank" baseURL: nil];
[webView stopLoading];
```

Swift

```
// Make sure this code is called before `removeFromSuperview`
webView.delegate = nil
webView.loadHTMLString("about:blank", baseURL: nil)
webView.stopLoading()
```

Comment: Update: Apple is rejecting any apps that still uses `UIWebView` - so please move over to `WKWebView` as needed.